# How to make latexindent format recursively all files put within \input{}?

Tags: latexindent

Since there is no `--recursive` option, I wonder how to recursively format all entries in `\input{}` present in the main `.tex` file.

Comment: `latexindent` can format multiple files in one call, so for example, `latexindent *.tex` to format all `.tex` files in the current directory

Comment: @cmhughes The problem is that the `.tex` files are not necessarily in the root directory

Comment: `latexindent dir1/*.tex dir2/*.tex`

Comment: @cmhughes This approach, although straightforward and obvious, does not provide a generic solution. I don't want to care about passing directories location that `latexindent` should run.

Answer (score 1):

Due to lack of apparent solution for this this issue, the following shell command forces `latexindent` to run for every `\input{}` entry found in the main `.tex` file:

```sh
grep -oP "(?<=\\\\input{)[^}]+" main.tex | while read file; do
    latexindent --silent --overwrite ${file}
done
```

where `main.tex` is the main latex file with your `\input{}` entries. That is  a ad-hoc solution, though. I would like to have a more elegant way out.